# More professional macros

Tags: c, macros, cross-platform

I'm a fairly young programmer. Just in my junior year of college, and I picked up C this summer in an attempt to better my abilities.

I'm just getting started on a model renderer in C, and I want it to be cross platform.

I'm using OpenGL and SDL, and I'm compiling them in GCC natively in ubuntu for the linux version, and in MinGW for windows.

The problem is that compiling an opengl + sdl app in MinGW wants me to change the main function's declaration line.

The normal way: `int main(int argc, char **argv);`

The MinGW winapi way: `int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd);`

the way I am doing this is completely ghetto

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    #define MAIN WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
#else
    #define MAIN main(int argc, char **argv)
#endif

int MAIN {
    return 0;
}
```

my question is: is there a more professional way of doing this?

Comment: What if you compile with `-mno-windows`?

Comment: @Kerrek SB No, using -mno-windows still produces an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something straightforward like

```
void doMyStuff(void) {
   ...
}

#ifdef _WIN32
  WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                  LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd) {
    doMyStuff();
    ExitProcess(0); // or whatever
  }
#else
  int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    doMyStuff();
    return 0 ;
  }
#endif
```

It's slightly longer than your version, but it's crystal clear *and* gives you somewhere to put the platform-specific startup code that you're bound to need once your program has to do something interesting.

(By the way, I think Windows programs can equally well use the standard main() entry point -- at least that's supposedly the case for Visual C/C++. All of the legacy parameters to WinMain can be gotten from explicit API calls if you need them. However, since you'll want some platform-specific startup code anyway, it doesn't really matter).

Comment: hmm... this could work. Windows program can use the standard main() entry point, but when i link in the mingw32 libopengl32.a it links libming32.a which looks for a WINAPI WinMain() entry point.

Comment: I'm going to hold off confirming this as the answer to see if something else I like is suggested. This is acceptable though.

Comment: A good Windows compiler generates a WinMain for you and makes it call the main() function with the required arguments. Perhaps you should link in some more code, like an object file that contains a startup stub? Usually the compiler takes care of this, and you don't have to call the linker manually.

Comment: this is gcc in mingw. This is hard core GNU stuff. Nothing is automatic.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since they are two different signatures, there might be functionality for each that's independent, but then some common code, so I think a clean way to handle it would be: have the Win function handle any windows-specific stuff, have the normal main() handle the C-specific stuff, and then separate out common functionality into a function you could call from both. So, something like this:

#### main_proxy.c

```
#ifdef _WIN32
  #include "WinMain.c"
#else
  #include "main.c"
#endif
```

#### WinMain.c

```
MAIN WINAPI WinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstance, 
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, 
    int nShowCmd
)
{
    // WinMain specific initialization
    // .. etc ...

    mainCommon();

    // WinMain specific cleanup
    // .. etc ...
}
```

#### main.c

```
MAIN main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // main specific initialization
    // .. etc ...

    commonMain();

    // main specific cleanup
    // .. etc ...
}
```

Comment: lol :) I mean, what are ya lookin for? is it the params that bother you?  I did get to thinking about it, and really if there some windows-specific code, but most of it common, just forget about the params, handle the non-Windows specific stuff in main(), the Windows specific stuff in WinMain, and then the common stuff in mainCommon(), which could be called by both.  Then no need for #ifdefs in your function, nor any need for the static params.  Actually I like that a lot better, I will be happy to update.

Comment: There's no need to store `hInstance` and `hPrevInstance` -- they are completely useless in win32 and only present in the `WinMain` prototype for reasons of source compatibility with old 16-bit code. `lpCommandLine` and `nShowCmd` are similarly redundant -- see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/05/25/10168020.aspx).

Comment: oh, didn't realize; haven't touched the raw API since ... well, let's just say a very long time ago ;)  but, okay; so perhaps it's as simple as calling a couple of functions to get the paramters that have the equivalent of `argc` and `argv` and pass those to the commonMain; I just wanted to give a strategy that could work. :)